# Laravel 5.6 and laravel-ckeditor

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor

I installed it with composer, added the providor, published it and even did npm run dev.
but everytime i want to replace my textarea with the editor, it doesn´t want to appear.

the textarea disappears, but there is no ckeditor

thanks!

Comment: Code? Any errors?

Comment: <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

Comment: {{ Form::textarea('description', '', ['id' => 'editor', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Beschreibung']) }}

Comment: <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
</script>

Comment: i did it exactly the same way than in my other projects. There it works just fine.

Comment: my files: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ah3_SNBdZMQYvBE-ZV3i_cLrEyTY thanks :)

Comment: You should check js file including is correct or not.

Comment: I've done it the same way than in the documentation <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

Comment: In my other projects it works perfect this way

Comment: Consider [edit]ing your question to show code, instead of adding unsuitably formatted comments.

Comment: Take the [tour] and reading [ask] might also provide you with some insights.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the **defer** worked for me as well in Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete "defer" on

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

So it should be like this :

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! finally it workes :) the only question left is why?

Answer (score -2):

syntax errors is why it did not work before. Having a statement outside of the "" is most likely why.